# Boost Shared Pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

I am new to boost and I came across the boost pointer.

```
float *value = new float[9]; 
value[0] = 5; ...
```

The above is my initial c++ code.

I converted the above to boost shared pointer

```
boost::shared_ptr<float> value (new float);
```

But when I try to add to value it gives me error that i cant use operator[].

I guess this is too basic, but can I get some info on how to add values to memory pointed by the boost pointer.

Comment: @iharob Why luckily?

Comment: Boost ugly? It's one of the most respected C++ libraries there is. Many things from Boost find their way into the standard (e.g. shared_ptr) such is the level of authority is has on the C++ community. The Spirit EBNF grammar parsing library is simply brilliant.

Comment: This is bad for two reasons. C++ now has a standard shared point, `std::shared_ptr` so you should use that rather than boosts offering. Further, unless you have a significant reason otherwise, you should `std::vector` or `std::array` for 'array like' things.

Comment: @Bathsheba: That's an appeal to authority. Boost has just as much crap as anywhere else- sometimes more. And finding your way into the Standard is no mark of quality- see `std::async`, `std::future`, `std::thread`, `std::vector<bool>`, `u8` literals, and so many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::shared_ptr<>` is not designed to be used to hold an array that's "decayed" to a pointer.

For starters, it wouldn't `delete` the memory correctly on destruction (it would call `delete` rather than `delete[]`.) You'd have to build your own deallocator to circumvent this. Possible but tedious.

Keep things simple: use `std::vector<float>`. In the current standard, the underlying data are guaranteed to be contiguous, and `data()` can be used to extract the underlying array.

Comment: Thanks I finally understand why  I was getting an error message. Besides that as you mentioned std::vector<>. If I use instead just float value[9] = {} to allocate memory do you think it is good.